# Does Microsoft requires that in order to support S0ix sleep, S3 must be disabled? Where is it documented?

Tags: sleep, standby, microsoft

I've read that Microsoft requires that machines supporting the S0ix sleep state, must not support (present) the S3 state.

Is this true? Is this officially documented somewhere?

I was looking for an official reference, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

No, Microsoft does not require it - it's rather the hardware vendors that
do it.

Both Intel and AMD were switching away from S3 sleep, so some vendors
don't have S3 options in the BIOS any more.

On the other hand, S0ix support is coming together even on AMD platforms
which were a little late to the party. Once it's working decently,
it will depend more on Windows than the manufacturer's firmware
to suspend components correctly, which might work better than depending
on the firmware.

Some manufacturers have brought back S3 through BIOS updates,
so things are still changing. It's too soon to know what will be
the end result.